# option force_s3tc_enable overridden by environment

Tags: javascript, node-webkit

I'm writing in NodeWebKit and the problem is when I use the select input:

```
<select class="form-control"/>
   <option>Value</option>
</select>
```

When it shows up, it doesn't have any dropdown value. Then when I click it the error:

```
ATTENTION: default value of option force_s3tc_enable overridden by environment.
```

Shows up.

When I checked the DOM it is showing:

```
<select class="form-control"/></select>
<option>Value</option>
```

How could the `option` value be suddenly outside?

Answer (score 3):

Your `select` element is actually closing on the first line.

```
<select class="form-control"/>
```

Having `/>` at the end of a HTML tag is called a *self-closing tag*, so the renderer sees that as the end of the tag.  That is why the rendered DOM shows `<option>` as being outside of the `select` element.

The fix is simple, remove the `/`:

```
<select class="form-control">
   <option>Value</option>
</select>
```